# Replace url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My image url

```
<img src="http.://8.37.229.144:8999/wapka_img.php?pid=4668758&fid=52869690&type=4&size=240&filename=240.jpg/>
```

And I want to change the url into

```
<img src"http.://8.37.229.144:8999/wapka_img.php?pid=4668758&fid=52869690&type=4&size=120&filename=120.jpg"/>
```

Can you help me

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hints: `window.location.search` and `window.location.href`

Comment: Look into get requests and how to pass them in JavaScript. When you have done so it should be clear

Comment: what you changed at all? only size 240 to 120. is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector("img").forEach(function(elem) {
   elem.src = elem.src.replace("=240" , "=120");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use template literals :-
e.g:-

```
let url = `http.://8.37.229.144:8999/wapka_img.php?pid=4668758&fid=52869690&type=4&size=${size}&filename=${size}.jpg`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some IMGs URL in a page, you can use jquery and regex to identify the images you want to change, and replace their url within a given pattern.

```
var rx = /....../i; //The [regex][1] pattern for your URLs

//Iterate over all the images...
$('img')
    .filter(img=>rx.test(img.src)) //... filter those match the url requirement...
    .each((index,img)=>img.replace(rx,'[new_url_pattern]'); //...replace the URLs.
```